# 'npm ERR! missing script: ngcc' error with NPM

Tags: angular, npm

From one day to another my project in Visual Studio Code started to show this two errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkBOm.png)

In fact, almost all tags from angular material are marked as error not recognizing as tags.

I tried using npm run ngcc but this error appeared:

```
npm ERR! missing script: ngcc
```

Also, i tried to reinstall npm but is the same.

Comment: Do you mix `yarn` and `npm` as package manager? Don't so that, just use one of both.

Comment: No, i never installed yarn, just npm

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, it may be due to Angular Ivy, which angular version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should set **ivy** compiler to false because that's the new compiler that is standard in the latest **Angular** versions, so I think that should be the last option if you can't get it to work.

[Ivy compiler](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

> Ivy is the code name for Angular's next-generation compilation and
> rendering pipeline. With the version 9 release of Angular, the new
> compiler and runtime instructions are used by default instead of the
> older compiler and runtime, known as View Engine.
>
> AOT compilation with Ivy is faster and should be used by default. In
> the angular.json

Try delete `node_modules` and installing dependencies from `package.json` will hopefully fix the problem.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

This command will remove `node_modules` and then **install** the dependencies from your `package.json` file.

**OR:**

It could also work to updated **angular cli**, **material**(If you use it) and **core**, and other modules needed for your project, then updated **npm** and **typescript** package, which could also solve the problem.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
npm update @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Then check that your **build-angular** is set to the same version that you use for **Angular**:

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular": "Your current version of angular"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

To your tsconfig.json file and then turning VSCode off and on again.